# data being overwritten when outputting data from stream analytics to powerbi

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

lately I've been playing around with Stream Analytics queries with PowerBI as output sink. I made a simple query which retrieves the total count of http responsecodes of our website requests over time and groups them by date and response code. 
The input data is retrieved from a storage account which holds BLOB storage. This is my query:

```
SELECT
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,R.context.data.eventTime), DATEPART(month,R.context.data.eventTime),DATEPART(day,R.context.data.eventTime),0,0,0,0) as datum,     
    request.ArrayValue.responseCode,
    count(request.ArrayValue.responseCode)
INTO
  [requests-httpresponsecode]
FROM
  [cvweu-internet-pr-sa-requests] R TIMESTAMP BY R.context.data.eventTime
OUTER APPLY GetArrayElements(R.request) as request
GROUP BY DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,R.context.data.eventTime), DATEPART(month,R.context.data.eventTime),DATEPART(day,R.context.data.eventTime),0,0,0,0), request.ArrayValue.responseCode, System.TimeStamp
```

Since continuous export became active on 3 september 2018, I chose a job start time of 3 september 2018. Since I am interested in the statistics until today, I did not include a date interval so I am expecting to see data from 3 september 2018 until now (20 december 2018). The job is running fine without errors and I chose PowerBI as an output sink. Immediately I saw the chart being propagated starting from 3 september grouped by day and counting. So far, so good. A few days later I noticed the output dataset didnt start from 3 september anymore but from 2 December until now. Apparently data is being overwritten.

The following link says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard

"*defaultRetentionPolicy: BasicFIFO: Data is FIFO, with a maximum of 200,000 rows.*"

But my output table does not have close to 200.000 rows:

```html
datum,count,responsecode
2018-12-02 00:00:00,332348,527387
2018-12-03 00:00:00,3178250,3282791
2018-12-04 00:00:00,3170981,4236046
2018-12-05 00:00:00,2943513,3911390
2018-12-06 00:00:00,2966448,3914963
2018-12-07 00:00:00,2825741,3999027
2018-12-08 00:00:00,1621555,3353481
2018-12-09 00:00:00,2278784,3706966
2018-12-10 00:00:00,3160370,3911582
2018-12-11 00:00:00,3806272,3681742
2018-12-12 00:00:00,4402169,3751960
2018-12-13 00:00:00,2924212,3733805
2018-12-14 00:00:00,2815931,3618851
2018-12-15 00:00:00,1954330,3240276
2018-12-16 00:00:00,2327456,3375378
2018-12-17 00:00:00,3321780,3794147
2018-12-18 00:00:00,3229474,4335080
2018-12-19 00:00:00,3329212,4269236
2018-12-20 00:00:00,651642,1195501
```

EDIT: I have created the STREAM input source according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-quick-create-portal. I can create a REFERENCE input as well, but this invalidates my query since APPLY and GROUP BY are not supported and I also think STREAM input is what I want according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-add-inputs.

What am I missing? Is it my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my query was the problem. I had to use **TUMBLINGWINDOW(day,1)** instead of **System.TimeStamp**. 
**TUMBLINGWINDOW** and **System.TimeStamp** produce exactly the same chart output on the frontend, but seem to be processed in a different way in the backend. This was not reflected to the frontend in any way so this was confusing. I suspect something is happening in the backend due to the way the query is processed when not using **TUMBLINGWINDOW** and you happen to hit the 200k row per dataset limit sooner than expected. The query below is the one which is producing the expected result.

```
SELECT
    request.ArrayValue.responseCode,
    count(request.ArrayValue.responseCode),
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,R.context.data.eventTime), DATEPART(month,R.context.data.eventTime),DATEPART(day,R.context.data.eventTime),0,0,0,0) as date     
INTO
  [requests-httpstatuscode]
FROM
  [cvweu-internet-pr-sa-requests] R TIMESTAMP BY R.context.data.eventTime
OUTER APPLY GetArrayElements(R.request) as request
GROUP BY DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,R.context.data.eventTime), DATEPART(month,R.context.data.eventTime),DATEPART(day,R.context.data.eventTime),0,0,0,0),
        TUMBLINGWINDOW(day,1), 
        request.ArrayValue.responseCode
```

As we speak my stream analytics job is running smoothly and producing the expected output from 3 september until now without data being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are streaming to a [**Streaming** dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdataset#datasetmode). Streaming datasets doesn't store the data in a database, but keeps only the last hour of data. If you want to keep the data pushed to it, then you must enable `Historic data analysis` option, when you create the dataset:

[image]

This will create **PushStreaming** dataset (a.k.a. Hybrid) with basicFIFO retention policy (i.e. about 200k-210k records kept).

Comment: First, thanks for your reply and suggestion. I can only create the output sink to PowerBI as described in my link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard). According to this, this already creates a data set in PushStreaming mode:

defaultRetentionPolicy: BasicFIFO: Data is FIFO, with a maximum of 200,000 rows.
defaultMode: pushStreaming: The dataset supports both streaming tiles and traditional report-based visuals (a.k.a. push).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that Azure Stream Analytics should be creating a "PushStreaming" or "Hybrid" dataset. Can you confirm that your dataset is correctly configured as "Hybrid" (you can check this attribute even after creation [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jN4A.png))?

If it is the correct type, can you please clarify the following:

1. Does the schema of your data change? If, for example, you send the datum `{a: 1, b: 2}` and then `{c: 3, d: 4}`, Azure Stream Analytics will attempt to change the schema of your table, which can invalidate older data.
2. How are you confirming the number of rows in the dataset?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. I can't seem to find that property in my dataset. I am using the web interface via https://app.powerbi.com. I am confirming the number of rows by making a chart of the dataset via https://app.powerbi.com. This dataset is linked to my account I signin with and it shown in the 'datasets' list on the left when I login.
I am confirming the number of records by choosing 'explore' in the upper menu bar, then choosing 'show data' and 'see records'. But it looks like I solved it - please see my answer.